# Python If Statement missing the else clause?

Tags: python

Super newbie question: why does option 1 and 2 come up with different values? The only difference is there is an else before `output[item] = output[item] + 1` in the second option. I'm not clear about what option 1 is doing.

**Option 1:**

```py
def item_count(input):
    output = {}
    
    for item in input:    
        if item not in output: 
            output[item] = 0
        
        output[item] = output[item] + 1
        
    return output
```

**Option 2**

```py
def item_count(input):
    output = {}
    
    for item in input:    
        if item not in output: 
            output[item] = 0
        
        else:
            output[item] = output[item] + 1
        
    return output
```

Comment: In option 1, the statement after the if block executes, *regardless* (or, in all executions of the loop).  In option 2, it only executes if the if statement validates to False.

Comment: Aside, `input` is a poorly chosen variable name as it’s overwriting the builtin `input()` function, inside your function.  A different name should be chosen.

Answer (score 3):

This is because in your first code snippet there is an `if` statement followed by `output[item] = 0`, since this second bit of code is not wrapped in an `else` block it will always be executed after the initial `if` block no matter what.

However, in your second code block, the `output[item] = 0` is wrapped in an `else` block. This means, that the line will **only** be executed if the `if` block does **not** run. Simply, in the second code block, the `if` and `else` are mutually exclusive. Both can’t be executed.

Answer (score 0):

In your option 2, the `if` and `else` serve as "either or", which means the code will only execute one of them: execute the `if` clause if item not in output or the `else` clause if the item is in the output.

However, in your option 1, the `output[item] = output[item] + 1` will always get executed no matter what happened in the `if` clause.